# How to convert my Sqlite tables to json array format for data storing and retrieving in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, json, sqlite

I have Sqlite tables created using DB Browser for Sqlite.

I implemented them for my GET/POST requests in my Reactjs project using controller.

Refer here - [github](https://github.com/CuriousDrive/EFCore.AllDatabasesConsidered/blob/main/SQLite/Steps.txt)

I was able to access and store my data from the table to my React App but my table provide me data in key and
value pairs i.e

```
{id:1 ,length:2,width:2,height:2}.
```

Now I want my data to be like :

```
        {
    "case1": {
        "type1": {
            "label":[
          {"label_id":"1", "label_name":xyz},
          {"label_id":"2", "label_name":rty},
          {"label_id":"3", "label_name":qwe}
       ]},
    "type2": {
       "label":[
        {"label_id":"1", "label_name":xyz},
        {"label_id":"2", "label_name":rty},
        {"label_id":"3", "label_name":qwe}
    ]},
}}
```

How to store such JSON format data to my Sqlite table and then to successfully send/retrieve the data from my React App to the server and vice-versa?

Comment: If you don't need to search inside the nested values you can JSON.stringify everything and store in the same field. Otherwise you would probably be better out with a nosql db if you need to nest values.

Comment: Hi @sorold thanks for answering my question, could you please give an example or any reference , thanks.